# Month to Date Paramaters when the month ends during a new month

Tags: sql

I run a month to date report every monday for activity through the previous friday.  The end date is today -3.

My problem occurs when the -3 date is in a new month.  For example July 31, 2014 is the last day of the month.  I want my report that will run on Monday, August 4 to return July 1 - July 31.

What happens now is that because of my -3, it will return a report Aug1 -Aug 1.  I need the logic to recognize that I want the previous month. Possibly useing the month of each Monday preceeding the end date???

Additonally, I'm not sure if my problem is in the start date or end date. I would like this report to run on a SSRS subscription and I haven't been able to come up with a solution.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Current settings:

```
Start = DateAdd(DateInterval.Month,
         DateDiff(DateInterval.Month,#01/01/1900#,Now()),#01/01/1900#)   
End = DateAdd("d", -3, Today())
```

Comment: You can use IIF() in the SSRS expression to do one formula if a condition is true, and a different formula if it is false.   That way you can use whatever cutoff point you want to decide if you want MTD, or previous month.

Comment: "...when the month ends during a new month"

Answer (score 0):

Another option you may want to consider if it always runs on a monday, is don't make the startdate and enddate parameters.  You can instead have them as variables within your procedure that gets calculated off of GETDATE().

```
SELECT @EndDate = DATEADD(day,-3,GETDATE())
SELECT @StartDate = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @EndDate), 0)
```